# Delay Devise Confirmable email being sent until new user is "approved"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am building a rails application using devise for authentication - including `:confirmable` functionality.  While many new users will be automatically authenticated based on their email address, some will need to be manually approved by an admin.  How can I stop Devise from sending the confirmation email until a new user is manually approved (when required)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop Devise from sending the confirmation e-mail by removing `:confirmable` from your model where you use it (i.e. "User" model). Also, you can manipulate the timeframe for which the confirmation e-mail will be sent by going into the `devise.rb` file, located in your initializers, and scrolling down to the section for `:confirmable` and changing the period of time. This is also the file that really allows you to customize a lot of Devise's functionality.

Additionally, I would recommend watching Railscasts episodes 209 and 210 (all about Devise).

Here's [Episode #209](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise)

And [Episode #210](http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise)

Both of these Railscasts really helped me with properly installing and configuring Devise to fit my application.

Hope this helps!